# Does Pusher work with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, pusher

I am trying to build a mobile app that would receive WebSocket notifications. I plan on using Pusher as my provider for WebSockets. I also plan on using PhoneGap to develop my app on but I am not sure if PhoneGap would be compatible with Pusher's JS library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pusher works with PhoneGap. You can find the details in this FAQ:
http://pusher.tenderapp.com/kb/faq/does-pusher-work-with-phonegap-yes